# private field can't be edited error when struct moved out of lib.rs

Tags: rust

I am moving some code from `lib.rs` to a separate file `db.rs` and getting the following error `field entries of struct Db is private`.

File `lib.rs`

```
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Db {
    entries: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<String, Bytes>>>,
}
impl Db {
    pub fn new() -> Db {
        Db {
            entries: Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new())),
        }
    }
}
```

File `src/handler.rs`.

```
use crate::Db;
use bytes::Bytes;
use core::result::Result;

pub struct Handler {
    db: Db,
}

impl Handler {
    pub fn new(db: Db) -> Handler {
        Handler { db: db }
    }

    pub fn write(&mut self, arr: &[String]) -> Result<&str, &'static str> {
        let key = &arr[1];
        let value = &arr[2];

        let val = value.clone();

        let p = &self
            .db
            .entries // Getting error here. 
            .borrow_mut()
            .insert(String::from(key), Bytes::from(val));
```

At this point everything is working fine. But I get the error at `.entries` when I move the code rom `lib.rs` to a separate file `db.rs` and change the `lib.rs` to following code.
File `lib.rs`

```
mod db;
pub use db::Db;
```

File `db.rs` after taking out the code from `lib.rs`.

```
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Db {
    entries: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<String, Bytes>>>,
}
impl Db {
    pub fn new() -> Db {
        Db {
            entries: Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new())),
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why does the compiler complain about entries field being private when the code is moved to the `db.rs` file but the same code works fine when present in the `lib.rs` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a public / private visibility issue. In Rust, by default, all items are "private", that is, their visibility is restrained to the module where they are defined. Each file implicitly defines a module, which explains why you would get different behavior by simply moving some code to a new file.

Besides that, it's also good to know that, in a struct, fields also have a visibility (which is again private by default). That is, even if you have a `pub` struct, a third party will be able to use that type in their function signature, for example, but not access the fields. To change that, just add the visibility before the field:

```rust
pub struct PublicStruct {
    pub public_field: u32,
    private_field: bool,
}
```